# unable to get form elements by using form name in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I am having an issue with accessing my form by it's name.  When I use document.form[0].mylink.value it recognizes the value and outputs to the innerHTML that I specify.  However, when I use document.myform.mylink.value it doesn't seem to recognize the form.  I have tried this in chrome 6.0 and also firefox 3.6.3 and get the same result in both.  I really need to be able to access my form values by using the form name (instead of document.form[0]), any ideas why document.myform.mylink.value doesn't work?

```
<form name="myform">
<table>
<tr><td valign="middle" align="center">
    <div id="textResponse"></div>
</td></tr>
<tr><td height="30" valign="middle" align="center">
    <input name="mylink" value="Enter a URL" size="31" />
</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top" align="center">
    <a href="javascript:submitForm2();">Click</a>
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm2(){
    //This one does NOT work:
    my_link = document.myform.mylink.value;
    //This one also does NOT work:
    //my_link = document.forms['myform'].mylink.value;
    //This one works:
    //my_link = document.forms[0].mylink.value;

    document.getElementById("textResponse").innerHTML="<p>"+my_link+"</p>";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is certainly not XHTML (Transitional) valid. `action` is a required attribute for `form` elements. It should at least be set, even if it's empty.

Comment: i'm a little late but the reason it's not working might be because you're missing the "type" attribute. I know by default it's text, not sure if it's actually mandatory though.

Answer (score 20):

Technically what you have should work ok... the full syntax below should also work:

```
var my_link = document.forms['myform'].elements['mylink'].value;
```

If by chance your variable in your "real" code is `"mylink"` *not* `"my_link"` you will get failures in IE as it will auto-reference the form element, not the value you are trying to extract.

That all said, your code *as posted*... **works just fine in Firefox/IE** (demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ymg8W/ )