# when i click on radio button, i got undefined message in jsp. what is the issue?

Tags: javascript, jsp

On click on radio button want to show the id value but when i click on radio button it shows undefined message. why it is happening?

```
<script language="javascript>
function openSubrurbicPopup(){
 alert(document.frmRubric.rubricid.value);}
</script>
<% 
try{
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database", "root",   "admin");
        String sql = "select * from table where parentid='0'";
        rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
    %>
        <form name="frmRubric" method="post" >
    <%  while(rs.next()){
            String id = rs.getString("id");
    %>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" onclick="openSubrurbicPopup()" />
            <input type="text" name="rubricid" value="<%=id%>" /><br>
        <%}%>
        </form>
    <%}catch(Exception e){
        out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
    %>
</body></html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927250/unable-to-get-form-elements-by-using-form-name-in-javascript

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just try like this. pass the textbox value in function.

```
onclick="openSubrurbicPopup('<%=id%>');"
```

And in your javascript function,

```
function openSubrurbicPopup(value){
       alert(value);
}
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: you are welcome. Your upvote/accept this as answer will give more significance to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check the radio button Element(DOM) is loaded or not.

If radio button is loaded means, Please try with the code. Sure it will helpful for you.

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

 if (document.forms['frmRubric'].el[i].type === 'radio' && document.forms['jobView'].el[i].name === 'radio')
 {
    if(document.forms['frmRubric'].el[i].checked == true )
    {
      alert( "val = " + document.forms['frmRubric'].el[i].value );
    }
 }else {
      alert('Element not loaded");
  }
}
```

Comment: nothing is happening on click. 
i also want to know. when i add 

<input type="text" name="vali" value="test" >

line just before the <body> tag and print its value using javascript using same method only by changing field name, then it show the value properly rather undefined. why this is so?